# Share to multiple accounts via Sharekit for iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

Is there a way to select multiple accounts to share to using http://getsharekit.com? For example, I want the user to hit the share button, and share to multiple Facebook and Twitter accounts. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible but you need to be logged in the sites before sharing the data on them. You can call function for sharing data on facebook and twitter one by one. And Sharekit provides very easy way of sharing data on multiple sites.